# Unity3D : Pause menu boolean not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, boolean

When the player hits P button, it will pause the game but it won't work

What am I doing wrong here ?
I declared the private var ispaused

```
private var ispaused = false;
```

Here is my code

```
function Update () {
if(Input.GetKeyDown("p")){
if(!ispaused){
Time.timeScale = 0;
ispaused = true;
}
if(ispaused){
Time.timeScale = 1;
ispaused = false;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: You're right, the key mapping was correct after all.

The second if statement needs to be an `else if`. Now you're going through both if statements each time you hit p, effectively setting the boolean to `true` and then immediately `false` again.

Here's the working code:

```
function Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("p")) {
        if (!ispaused) {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            ispaused = true;
        } else if (ispaused) {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            ispaused = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't with the input but with the if statement of ispaused